# fopen and fputs in c

Tags: c, fopen, fputs

Hello I am struggling with fopen and fputs when trying to write data to a file.

In particular, the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
       FILE * fp;

       fp = fopen ("file_out.txt", "a+");
       fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2016);

       fclose(fp);

       return(0);
    }
```

Gives me this output:
We are in 2016

This is what I was expecting and hoping for.

However, when I change

```
fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2016);
```

to

```
fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 3333);
```

and recompile and run I still get the same output as before!  Meaning, 2016 is printed, not 3333. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you recompile?, it has nothing to do with the code for sure.

Comment: Most likely answers: you forgot to recompile, you forgot to re-run, or you're looking at the wrong file.

Comment: Do u saved the file first ? Before compiling!! If u r in code::blocks then

Comment: Delete your file, run the new code and tell us what happens.

Comment: You must be running the old version.  Make sure you (1) Save your source file (2) Recompile your source file (3) Re-link your executable.  One of these steps has to have been skipped.  I suggest deleting the old executable and the old .o file, then rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have opened the file in append mode `fp = fopen ("file_out.txt", "a+");` therefore what ever you write will get appended to file.  And I guess the utility which reads the file is just reading the first line of file. Hence you are getting `We are in 2016` everytime.